# Reduce the number of workers on a machine in Python-RQ?

Tags: python, redis, python-rq

What is a good way to Reduce the number of workers on a machine in Python-RQ?

[According to the documentation](http://python-rq.org/docs/workers/), I need to send a SIGINT or SIGTERM command to one of the worker processes on the machine:

> #### Taking down workers
>
> If, at any time, the worker receives `SIGINT` (via <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd>) or `SIGTERM` (via `kill`),  the worker wait until the currently running task is finished, stop the work loop and gracefully register its own death.
>
> If, during this takedown phase, `SIGINT` or `SIGTERM` is received again,the worker will forcefully terminate the child process (sending it `SIGKILL`), but will still try to register its own death.

This seems to imply a lot of coding overhead:

- Would need to keep track of the PID for the worker process
- Would need to have a way to send a SIGINT command from a remote machine

Do I really need to custom build this, or is there a way to do this easily using the Python-RQ library or some other existing library?

Comment: I'm not aware there is a generic solution for this, and most projects I know about implement a custom solution tailored to their peculiar needs.  So unless Python-RQ provides something out of the box (not familiar with it), you may need to custom build it.  It does not sound like so much work.

Comment: For 1, you may need to track the PID, and rq provides it https://github.com/nvie/rq/blob/master/rq/worker.py#L166

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Get all running workers using `rq.Worker.all()`
2. Select the worker you want to kill
3. Use `os.kill(worker.pid, signal.SIGINT)`